# Displaying QGIS's "Map Tips" in OpenLayers?

Tags: qgis, javascript, openlayers, jquery, ajax

Still a little new to QGIS and Openlayers.  How would you display QGIS's "Map Tips" into OpenLayers? I am currently using QGIS 2.18 and have the latest update in Openlayers. In QGIS, I have created a display in Map Tips showing a county's information when you hover over the county. Now need display the "Map Tips" into openlayers.

Now I know you can create map pop ups in OpenLayers but thinking that involves alot of code and wanted to see if it is possible that we can do it in QGIS.

OpenLayers basically takes images that get render by QGIS and display them in the map. I have applied the "Map Tips" within the outline layer and can display it in QGIS. I assume that with QGIS, it can render and create the image with the "Map Tips" inside an image.  What I need it to do is whenever someone hovers over the county name or the county's area within the map, the "Map Tips" display will pop up and show the user information.  I feel that there has to be a way to display the "Map Tips" in OpenLayers.

Here is part of the code from OpenLayers to pull up that particular layer:

```
<script>
     var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
            code: 'EPSG:3857',
            extent: [-11822316, 4304590, -9430259, 6360040]
     });

    var  extent = [-11822316, 4304590, -9430259, 6360040];

 var outline_layer = new ol.layer.Image({
        extent: extent,
        label: 'outline_layer',
        visible: true,
         source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                url: '/map/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?MAP=mapping.qgs&',
                crossOrigin: 'anonymous',                                           
                params: {
                    'LAYERS': 'Outlines',
                    'FORMAT': 'image/png'
                },
            serverType: 'qgis',                                         
        })
    });
var map = new ol.Map({
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
     new ol.control.ScaleLine()
]),
    layers: [ background_layer,
        outline_layer],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: projection,
            center: [-10597609, 5335488],
            extent: extent,
            zoom: 1.8
    })
});

var changeLayer = function changeLayer(ev) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    map.getLayers().forEach(function (layer) {
        if (layer.get('label') === val) {
        layer.setVisible(checked);                                              
        } else {
            layer.setVisible(false);                                                                    
            outline_layer.setVisible(true); 
            jurisdiction_names.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    $('input:checkbox').not($(this)).each(function () {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);                                             
    });
};

$('input').each(function () {
    $(this).on('change', changeLayer);
});
```

Is there a way to display QGIS "Map Tips" in OpenLayers?

Comment: Map tips seem to be specific to the QGIS application https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#maptips

If that is the case then in OpenLayers you would need to obtain the information with a GetFeatureInfo request and format the result using similar logic to that used in QGIS, for example by combining the https://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/getfeatureinfo-image.html and https://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/popup.html OpenLayers examples you could produce https://codesandbox.io/s/getfeatureinfo-image-p7l0g

Comment: The QGIS documentation https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/services.html#getfeatureinfo says GetFeatureInfo requests can take an optional `WITH_MAPTIP` parameter so while you would still need a GetFeatureInfo request to obtain the tip there should be no need to duplicate the logic used to format it and could simple use `content.innerHTML = properties.map_tip;` (or something similar) to display it.

Comment: I assume you would still have to do the openlayers popup if were to take the option of WITH_MAPTIP but the HTML content should already be made.

Comment: Yes. The property name is `maptip` and I presume it is an html string - unfortunately all the qgis cloud examples I tried return an empty string so I could not confirm that, but it should be easy for you to confirm with your server.  Note that application/json would be the preferred format to use with javascript but the cloud examples were not configured for that.

Comment: qgis cloud example: https://qgiscloud.com/be_poloind/Polo_Industrial_Cadastro_Web/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetFeatureInfo&id=Polo_Industrial_Cadastro_Web1566421860443&layers=Eixo+Logradouro,Meio+Fio,Unidade+Construida,Lote&query_layers=Eixo+Logradouro,Meio+Fio,Unidade+Construida,Lote&x=51&y=51&i=51&j=51&height=101&width=101&srs=EPSG:31984&crs=EPSG:31984&bbox=361112.0645833333,7949421.066666667,361165.5104166666,7949474.5125&info_format=text%2Fxml&with_geometry=true&with_maptip=true&feature_count=10&FI_POINT_TOLERANCE=16&FI_LINE_TOLERANCE=8&FI_POLYGON_TOLERANCE=4